# For what values of ‎$‎a>0‎$‎, ‎$‎x(-\ln(x))^a \geq (1-x)(-\ln(1-x))^a‎$ ‎if ‎$‎0<x<0.5‎$‎?

Tags: calculus

‎Suppose   $$f(x)=x(-\ln(x))^a-(1-x)(-\ln(1-x))^a,$$
where ‎$‎a>0‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎x\in (0,0.5)‎$‎. It is clear that ‎$‎\lim_{x \rightarrow ‎0^+}f(x)=0=‎\lim_{x \rightarrow ‎0.5^-}f(x)‎$. ‎The ‎question ‎is: ‎‎
u‎nder what conditions for ‎$‎a‎$‎, ‎$‎f(x)\geq 0‎$ for  ‎‎$‎x\in (0,0.5)‎$. I‎ ‎guess ‎$‎f(x)\geq 0‎$‎ for  ‎‎$‎a> \ln(2)‎$.‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

Comment: Have you tried to derivate ?

Comment: Yes, but I can not find the root of $f^'(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about your claim that "$a>\ln2$". You can see the antisymmtery at $x=0.5$ if you consider $f(x)$ on $(0,1)$. So, if you want $f(x) > 0$ on $(0, 0.5)$ then you must have $f(x)<0$ on $(0.5, 1)$.

That means you need $f$ to be decreasing around $x=0.5$ or in other words $f$ has to have negative slope at $x=0.5$ so $f'(0.5)<0$ must be satisfied (and this is also sufficient). Here is the derivative of $f$ given by WolframAlpha:

$f'(x) = -a(-\ln(1-x))^{a-1} + (-\ln(1-x))^{a} + (-\ln(x))^{a} - a(-\ln(x))^{a-1}$

$f'(0.5) = -a(\ln 2)^{a-1} + (\ln 2)^{a} + (\ln 2)^{a} - a(\ln 2)^{a-1} = 2(\ln 2)^{a-1}(\ln 2 - a) < 0$

$ \implies \ln 2 < a$.

Another approach may be considering concavity of $f(x)$ on $(0, 0.5)$ and convexity of $f$ on $(0.5, 1)$ again by the antisymmtery. That is, making $f''(x)<0$ on $(0, 0.5)$ and $f''(x)>0$ on $(0.5, 1)$ which implies $f''(0.5)=0$. However, it can be checked that $f''(0.5)=0$ holds whatever $a$ is. Thus, this approach will become far more complicated as you need to determine the sign of the second derivative.

Comment: ‎Dear ‎Turkun,‎
I really thank you for your suggestion ‎to ‎check ‎the‎ concavity or convexity of ‎$‎f‎$‎. I have done and if ‎$‎a\geq 1+\ln(2)‎$ ‎then ‎‎$‎f(x)‎$ ‎is‎ concave on ‎$‎(0,0.5)‎$‎. Thank you

Comment: @Jafar You are welcome.

Comment: If ‎‎$a\geq 1+\ln(2)‎$ ‎then ‎‎‎$f(x)‎$ ‎is‎ concave on $(0,e^{1−a})‎‎$ and if ‎‎$a \leq 1+\ln(2)‎$ ‎then ‎‎‎$f(x)‎$ ‎is‎ concave on ‎‎$(0,1−e^{1−a})‎‎$.